# Perfecto Mobile ScriptOnce - Is it Possible to perform an action on an object (not just retrieving the value) using html_id instead of control_id

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, automation, integration-testing, functional-testing

Working with MobileCloud Automation from Perfecto Mobile using **ScriptOnce** on a jquery-mobile application.

I want to find out if it is possible to perform an action on an object (not just retrieving the value) using **html_id** instead of Perfecto Mobile's **control_id**.

Background:
We have already created an object repository with **html_id** ids.

I want to have the **scriptOnce** automation more easily find the objects by the **html_id** values in our object repository.

Is it possible, and how do I set the html ids to be used?

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to work with html_id's or html_name's.
You need to check the "**show advanced parameters**" box and then just type the id or name of the html element.
If you work with their QTP solution, and say you want to put the user name in a text box with `id = userIdInput`, then the syntax would be something like that:

```
Device("DUT").MWebEdit("html_id:=userIdInput").Set "my_username"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.I didn't know about the **"show advanced parameters"** as I am more familiar with QTP. The syntax you provided is clear and correct.